# How can I activate the Friendly Service in eXo platform?

Tags: url-rewriting

Ive been trying a few days to activate the [FriendlyService](http://docs.exoplatform.com/PLF35/index.jsp?topic=/org.exoplatform.doc.35/ADM.Management.Friendly_service.html) in [exo-platfom](http://www.exoplatform.com/company/en/home) 3.5.x but have been unsuccessful so far.

In the section:

`administration > management`

There is a service called `Friendly Service` which allows eXo to rewrite a request URL to another URL (in a more readable format). However, this service is inactivated.

Can someone tell me how activate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.When starting server, you need to enable the profile 'friendly':
  Example: `./start_eXo.sh -Dfriendly`

2.When registering `FriendlyService`, you need to provide parameter `enable` as `true`:

```
<component>
  <key>org.exoplatform.services.wcm.friendly.FriendlyService</key>
  <jmx-name>exo-service:type=FriendlyService</jmx-name>
  <type>org.exoplatform.services.wcm.friendly.impl.FriendlyServiceImpl</type>
  <init-params>
    <value-param>
      <name>enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </value-param>
    </init-params>  
</component>
```

Hope it helps..